# PivotTable filter not running and failing to apply

Tags: excel, vba, office365, pivot-table, powerpivot

I have a table which i have created from Power Pivot.

Im trying to apply a filter to the pivottable however it is constantly coming up with this error:
[image: Error]

its driving me crazy as it seems so simple yet wont work no matter what i try.

Everything online states this should work... Yet it doesnt at all.

```
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DATA").PivotTables("VQ_Table").PivotFields( _
        "[VQ_Table].[TM Name].[TM Name]").VisibleItemsList = Array("TM Name Here")
```

Please can someone advise?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you be more specific? What errors exactly do you get?

Comment: Hi Sorry it says "Unable to get the PivotFeilds property of the PivotTable class"

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that a specified pivot fields object exists.

```
Set pvtTable = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").PivotTable 
rw = 0 
For Each pvtField In pvtTable.PivotFields 
 rw = rw + 1 
 nwSheet.Cells(rw, 1).Value = pvtField.Name 
Next pvtField
```

Try to iterate over all pivot fields and write down their names.

Comment: I have ran this code and the table field shows correct to what is in my code above ?

Comment: Try to break the long line of property and method calls and see what property or method exactly throws an error.

Comment: Sorry i am unsure what you mean by this?

Comment: Too many different calls of properties and methods in the single line of code. Try to declare each property or method in a single/separate line and see which one exactly causes the issue.

Comment: Im not sure how to do this, please could you advise with some code?

Comment: Just declare each call on a separate line of code.

Comment: each call of what though? Im trying to get the filter on my pivot to change and it is coming up with an error. I dont know what you mean by "Just declare each call on a separate line of code." 

How do i break "ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DATA").PivotTables("VQ_Table").PivotFields( _
        "[VQ_Table].[TM Name].[TM Name]").VisibleItemsList = Array("TM Name Here")" into seperate lines of code its only one line as it is?

Comment: Each dot in the string stands for a method or property call.